# What is an effecient way to capture the username after the "@" on instagram using regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, instagram, instagram-api

In other words, if I made a call to the Instagram API and I wanted to capture the usernames of someone tagged in the comments, and I knew the comment was on the first line every time, what would be the most accurate way to capture the string (username) after the '@' that precedes a tagged user, and have that expression repeat for a known number of posts.

Matching characters wouldn't be useful since the tagged name constantly changes form post to post. So if the comment was "picture taken by @JohnSmith," what is the best way to capture the string immediately preceding with no known length or character value?

Implementation example- user wants to find the tagged photographer for all photos on a page. There are 100 photos on the @coolphotographer Instagram page and the photographer is tagged on the first line in the comments on each post.

Comment: http://blog.jstassen.com/2016/03/code-regex-for-instagram-username-and-hashtags/

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I added an answer from the above blog

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
(?:^|[^\w])(?:@)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)
```

**NOTE: Above regex is taken from [this](http://blog.jstassen.com/2016/03/code-regex-for-instagram-username-and-hashtags/) blog**

Thanks @RobbyCornelissen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Uses gsub.

"@JohnSmith".gsub('@', "")

Answer (score 0):

You can use next regexp

```
/@(\w+)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/5bgU2DtEqX

Comment: This works perfectly and is a succinct way to get the job done. Hope someone else can upvote it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Uses gsub.

"@JohnSmith".split("@").last